# Elemento button submetendo formulário. Como desativar?

Tags: html

Preciso separar o formulário em 2 divs diferentes, na mesma página.
Tentei o seguinte e não deu certo:

```
    <div id="div1">
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="Nome">
</form>
<button onclick="exibediv2()">
</div>
    <div id="div2">
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="Cidade">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<button onclick="exibediv1()">
</div>
```

Quando uso o submit no segundo form, ele não reconhece o valor do primeiro input. Como resolver isso?

[*Adicionado devido feedback dos comentários*]

> Quando deixo como um único `<form>` o primeiro `button` age como um
>   `submit`.

Comment: Se percebo bem o que precisas deves evitar fechar o primeiro form e criar o segundo. Acho que precisas algo assim https://jsfiddle.net/6szwunqm/ sem o `</form>...<form>` entre as divs.

Comment: Qual o JS da função exibediv1() e exibedv2() ?

Comment: Os scripts apenas alteram a posição das divs setando o display para block ou none.

Comment: Eu também pensei nisso, Sergio, porém quando eu não fecho o form, o botão que deveria exibir a div 2, funciona como um submit.

Answer (score 2):

O elemento [button](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) é definido por padrão para ser do tipo *submit* `type="submit"`. Exceto para versão anterior ao IE8 onde é definido como *button* `type="button"`.

Para desativar o tipo padrão, basta especificar dentro da própria tag:

```
<button type="button" />
```

Para o caso específico da pergunta, uma sugestão de como resolver:

```
<form method="post">
<div id="div1">
<input type="text" name="Nome">
<button type="button" onclick="exibediv2()">
</div>
<div id="div2">
<input type="text" name="Cidade">
<input type="submit">
<button type="button" onclick="exibediv1()">
</div>
</form>
```