# Como fazer Post de um método clicando num button type=button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, post, asp

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em que quando clicar num botão tenho de enviar um email. 
Tenho la minha página uma `input type=Text` e um `button type="button"` que com css ficou assim `->`.
Eu preciso que quando carregar nessa seta, seja enviado um email como está no código, e no corpo de email seja enviado também o que está na input text. Se o input text estiver vazia, deve dar erro e não fazer nada.

Eu clico no botão mas não faz nada. O que pode está acontecendo de errado?

Código que tenho para já:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Cegos Analytics | Lockscreen</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition lockscreen">
<!-- Automatic element centering -->
<div class="lockscreen-wrapper">
  <div class="lockscreen-logo">
   <img src="/Images/^082594892CD6A1E2D2CF4B7361463D84FEF2B4C6FEBD2707B5^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.png" alt="Cegos Logo">
  </div>
    <br />
  <!-- User name -->
  <div class="lockscreen-name"></div>

  <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->

    <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->
</div>

    <!-- lockscreen credentials (contains the form) -->
    <form class="lockscreen-credentials">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">


    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %> 
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>

  <script runat="server">

      public void SendEmail()
      {


          try
          {

              SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
              cliente.Host = "smtp.sapo.pt";
              cliente.EnableSsl = true;
              cliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("suportcegos@sapo.pt", "cegoc123456");

              MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
              mensagem.Sender = new MailAddress("suportcegos@sapo.pt");
              mensagem.From = new MailAddress("suportcegos@sapo.pt");
              mensagem.To.Add(new MailAddress("nsoares@cegoc.pt"));
              mensagem.Subject = "Pedido de suporte Plataforma Cegos Analytics";
              mensagem.Body = "Recebeu um pedido de suporte da  Plataforma Cegos Analytics para recuperação de password referente ao utilizador:";
              mensagem.IsBodyHtml = false;
              mensagem.Priority = MailPriority.High;

              cliente.Send(mensagem);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Response.Write("******EMAIL FAILED. PLEASE CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR**** See log file in C:\\Logs");
              CreateLogFiles(ex.Message);
              ErrorLog("C:\\Logs\\log.txt", ex.Message);
              Response.Write(ex.Message);

          }


      }

</script>  


        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="SendEmail()" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-muted"></i></button>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- /.lockscreen credentials -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.lockscreen-item -->
  <div class="help-block text-center">
    Enter your username to retrieve your session
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a href="../Default.aspx">Or sign in as a different user</a>
```

O que eu tenho essencialmente é uma pa´gina recoverpassword.aspx onde tenho isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Cegos Analytics | Lockscreen</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition lockscreen">
<!-- Automatic element centering -->
<div class="lockscreen-wrapper">
  <div class="lockscreen-logo">
   <img src="/Images/^082594892CD6A1E2D2CF4B7361463D84FEF2B4C6FEBD2707B5^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.png" alt="Cegos Logo">
  </div>
    <br />
  <!-- User name -->
  <div class="lockscreen-name"></div>

  <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->

    <!-- START LOCK SCREEN ITEM -->
  <div class="lockscreen-item">
    <!-- lockscreen image -->
    <div class="lockscreen-image">
      <img src="/Images/locked.jpg" alt="Locked Screen">
    </div>
    <!-- /.lockscreen-image -->
</div>

    <!-- lockscreen credentials (contains the form) -->
    <form class="lockscreen-credentials" action="RecoverPassword.aspx" method="post">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input id='user' type="Text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">    
    <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button id='enviar' type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-muted"></i></button>
         </div>

     </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- /.lockscreen credentials -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.lockscreen-item -->
  <div class="help-block text-center">
    Enter your username to retrieve your session
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a href="../Default.aspx">Or sign in as a different user</a>
  </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  <%--  <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />--%>
    <br />
  <div class="lockscreen-footer text-center">
        <p style="height: 42px" align="center">&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %> - <strong>Cegos Elearning Reports</strong>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.center -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.0 -->
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#enviar").click(function () {
               @SendEmail();//Insira aqui o código para chamar o sender email.
    });
</script>



            </form>

            </body>

</html>
```

e tenho na propria página tenho uma class recoverpasssword e la defini o metodo sendemail() que tem o codigo de enviar email. Quando clico no botão na página para enviar email ele não faz post nem envia o mail. 
Podem-me ajudar por favor?
Desculpem meus erros

Comment: Suas imagens estão quebradas. Tente fazer o upload novamente.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando chamar uma função ASP no evento `OnClick()` do JavaScript. Um não enxerga o outro pois o ASP executa no server e o JavaScript executa no browser do usuário.

## Sugestão

Modifique o tipo do elemento button `<button type="button"`...,
definindo com o tipo *submit* `<button type="submit"`...

Esse tópico pode ser interessante para saber mais: [Elemento button submetendo formulário. Como desativar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112154/elemento-button-submetendo-formul%C3%A1rio-como-desativar)

Defina também o atributo `action` do elemento `<form>`

```
<form class="lockscreen-credentials" action="pagina.aspx" method="post">
```

O arquivo pagina.asp é onde deve ter o script que postou

```
 public void SendEmail()
  {


      try
      {

          SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
          cliente...
```

## Runat=server

Caso queira usar com atributo runat="server":

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="SendEmail()" runat="server">
```

Troque por:

```
<asp:Button id="SendEmail" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="false" class="btn" onclick="SendEmail">
```

Comment: Já modei mas mesmo assim não executa o código nem envia o email.

Comment: cara faz post mas não esta enviando o email não.

Comment: Aí já é outro problema. A questão principal que era fazer o submit, já resolveu. Então não tem mais o que comentar. Evite perguntar várias coisas num único tópico. Pergunte uma coisa e resolva. Quando tiver outra dúvida / problema, abra um novo tópico. Leia as normas do site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour.